# PHP error if same username is entered

Tags: php, forms, passwords

Usernames and passwords are stored in a file, if a username already exits in the file it should tell the user that they can't use that password and reloads the page. Right now it's not doing that, it's going straight to commentsWall.php even though I type in the same username. What am I missing?

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Please enter your information to create a new login account</h1>
 <form method="post">
  Login Name:<input type = "text"  name = "name" value = "" required><br/>
  Password:<input type = "password" name = "pwd" value = "" required><br/>
  <input type = "submit" name="submit_btn" id = "submit" value = "submit"/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
 session_start();
 if($_POST){
  $handle = fopen("accounts.txt", "r");
  if(isset($_POST['name'])){
     $username = $_POST['name'];
     $file = file_get_contents('accounts.txt');
     $search = $username . ",";
     if(strpos($file, $search) !== FALSE){
        echo 'name already used, choose another';
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
     }
    fclose($handle);
  }
  if(isset($_POST['pwd'])){
     $password = $_POST['pwd'];
  }
  $text = $username . "," . $password . "\n";
  $fp = fopen("accounts.txt", 'a+') or die("Unable to open file!");
  if(fwrite($fp, $text)){
     echo "saved";
     fclose($fp);
     header("Location: commentWall.php");
  }
  else{
     echo "Unable to store credentials.";
     header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  }
}
?>
```

If you want to see commentsWall.php code just ask, but I don't think it's necessary to include.

Comment: You can't call `session_start()` after doing HTML output. Put that at the very top.

Comment: Still not working unfortunately

Comment: You should use a db. Did you set the permissions on `accounts.txt` so it isn't accessible to all users? You probably should have all that code before the HTML.

Comment: @user3572515 That wasn't intended as a solution, it was an unrelated comment. I've posted the solution in an answer.

Comment: A db is an obvious improvement but this is just a simple php assignment so I didn't think it necessary. I haven't set the permission, what should it be?

Comment: Oh my... plain text stored user file? Assignment or not. You should have been briefed about practices before any physical implementation

Comment: @user3572515 all you have to do is debug prints ... and traceback until you find the error. Check after every statement if it is works and print out the $file output and compare it to the other $search string - you will find out sooner or later. E.g. var_dump(strpos($file, $search));

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The script doesn't stop after detecting that the name is in use. You need to do:

```
if (strpos($file, $search) !== FALSE) {
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
}
```

Also, `header()` doesn't work if you've already produced output. You should move the block of HTML at the top to the `else` clause of the `if ($_POST)` test.

Answer (score 0):

At very least you need to restructure your code so that you don't send the login form unless there is no POST, or the login failed.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if($_POST){
  $handle = fopen("accounts.txt", "r");
  if(isset($_POST['name'])){
     $username = $_POST['name'];
     $file = file_get_contents('accounts.txt');
     $search = $username . ",";
     if(strpos($file, $search) !== FALSE){
        echo 'name already used, choose another';
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
     }
    fclose($handle);
  }
  if(isset($_POST['pwd'])){
     $password = $_POST['pwd'];
  }
  $text = $username . "," . $password . "\n";
  $fp = fopen("accounts.txt", 'a+') or die("Unable to open file!");
  if(fwrite($fp, $text)){
     echo "saved";
     fclose($fp);
     header("Location: commentWall.php");
  }
  else{
     echo "Unable to store credentials.";
     header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  }
} else {
?>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Please enter your information to create a new login account</h1>
 <form method="post">
  Login Name:<input type = "text"  name = "name" value = "" required><br/>
  Password:<input type = "password" name = "pwd" value = "" required><br/>
  <input type = "submit" name="submit_btn" id = "submit" value = "submit"/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: this will generate badly formed html though - echoing content outside of the html tags ~ though the `header` function calls will redirect anyway so probably not an issue